# MySQL select rows that end in full stop/period

Tags: mysql, select, period

I want to select all rows in a table that end in a full stop.

When I use the following query, I get no results.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE row LIKE '%.'
```

But I know there is data in the table that ends in a full stop.

I noticed something about the full stop causing issues in MATCH AGAINST, but that should be unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have no values that end in a period.

That seems simple enough.

First, see if there are any periods at all in the data:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE row LIKE '%.%'
```

If so, then period spaces are the issue:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE trim(row) LIKE '%.'
```

Comment: Period spaces was the issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use `RIGHT()` string function like below. See a [Demo Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/38e585/2)

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE RIGHT(`row`,1) = '.';
```